# How to check whether cells in a particular column of a html table is empty using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a html page in my web application where there are several forms and tables.
In following column 'Advert Id' is mandatory to be filled.

```html
<table id="mf-table" class="table table-hover">
<tbody>
<tr>
 <th>File Name</th>
 <th>Duration</th>
 <th>Category</th>
 <th>Comment</th>
 <th>Advert Name</th>
 <th>Advert Id</th>
</tr>
```

The content of the above table is to be added.

I want to check whether all the cells under the Advert Id column is filled. If not I want to get the Advert name of the relevant entry.

Currently I am able to check whether there is content in the table and if not a warning is displayed.

```
function saveAdminStatusAndTR(){
     var rowCount = $('#mf-table tr').length;
     if(rowCount == 1){ //case where there is no content in the table
        toastr.error('No media file has been uploaded', 'Approval Status');
     }else if(...){ //one of the cell under advert id is empty
          // Need to show a warning message indicating the advert names 
          where there is no advert id
     }else{
       //my code here
     }
 }
```

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Can I know the reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery selector :eq

```
$("table td:eq(POSITION)").each(function(idx) {...});
```

This link will be helpfull https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Hope this helps

Comment: answer seems to be not relevant to the question